# How to wait for an event in Emacs Lisp function?

Tags: emacs, elisp, w3m

I'm trying to write the simplest function: send a query to w3m browser and then find a particular place on the webpage:

```
(defun w3m-define-word (word)
  (interactive "sDefine: ")
  (progn (w3m-search "Dictionary" word)
         (set-window-start nil (search-forward "Search Results"))))
```

What is wrong here is that `w3m-search` does not wait until page reloads and `set-window-start` executes on the older page. Then the page reloads and places a cursor at the beginning of the buffer.

`(sleep-for ..)` between `w3m-search` and `set-window-start` helps, but since loading time is arbitrary, it is not very convenient.

How can I rewrite this function, so it would wait until buffer reloads and only then do the rest?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to accomplish this in elisp is using [hooks](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Hooks.html#Hooks).  So you'd need to see if w3m calls a hook when the page is loaded.  If so then you can register a hook function for that hook that does what you want.

It looks like `C-h v w3m-display-hook RET` is what you're looking for.  Here's a [good example](https://web.archive.org/web/20101223104508/http://nflath.com/2009/09/web-browsing-in-emacs) to start from.

Comment: Thank you, Ross. `w3m-display-hook` does the job at the right time.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case if anyone has same ideas, that's what I have ended up with thanks to Ross:

```
(defun w3m-goto-on-load (url)
  "Go to a position after page has been loaded."
  (cond
    ((string-match "domain" url)
      (progn
        (set-window-start nil (search-forward "Search" nil t) nil)))
    (t nil)))
(add-hook 'w3m-display-hook 'w3m-goto-on-load)
```

where `"domain"` is a keyword in URL to match and `"Search"` is the unique string to jump to. Certainly, `search-forward` can be replaced with `re-search-forward`, if more flexible search is required.